# CellValueChanged event for a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `DataRowView`. `DataGrid.BeginningEdit` is called before I start typing. `CellEditEnding` is called after the focus is lost. I need an event that fires whenever I type on a cell. What should I do?

```
private static ObservableCollection<DataRowView> _dataGridSrcCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataRowView>();
public static ObservableCollection<DataRowView> DataGridSrcCollection
{
  get
  {
    return _dataGridSrcCollection;
  }
  set
  {
    if (value != _dataGridSrcCollection)
    {
      _dataGridSrcCollection = value;        
    }  
  }
}
```

I am Binding each column programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any `CellValueChanged` event for `DataGrid` however assuming all your data-grid columns are text columns then you can use `TextChanged` event as follow:

Xaml:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridSrcCollection}" 
              SelectionUnit="Cell"
              SelectionMode="Single" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="your header" Binding="{Binding Path=YourProperty}" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="CellValueChanged" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void CellValueChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // your code
    }
```

Comment: But the SelectedItem is null for a cell. The set property of SelectedCell is called only when the SelectedRow changes. Not when I type in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you say you're binding the columns programmatically, you need to add `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` to those Bindings.

Then, you need to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of each of the DataRowView objects in your collection. The best way to do this, to avoid loose event handlers, would be in the `CollectionChanged` event of your ObservableCollection, like this:

```
private static ObservableCollection<DataRowView> _dataGridSrcCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataRowView>();
public static ObservableCollection<DataRowView> DataGridSrcCollection
{
    get
    {
        return _dataGridSrcCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _dataGridSrcCollection)
        {
            if (_dataGridScrCollection != null)
            {
                _dataGridScrCollection.CollectionChanged -= DataGridScrCollection_CollectionChanged;

                foreach (var row in _dataGridScrCollection)
                    row.PropertyChanged -= DataRowView_PropertyChanged;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                value.CollectionChanged += DataGridScrCollection_CollectionChanged;

                foreach (var row in value)
                    row.PropertyChanged += DataRowView_PropertyChanged;
            }

            _dataGridSrcCollection = value;        
        }  
    }
}

private void DataGridScrCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OldItems != null)
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
            ((DataRowView)item).PropertyChanged -= DataRowView_PropertyChanged;

    if (e.NewItems != null)
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            ((DataRowView)item).PropertyChanged += DataRowView_PropertyChanged;
}

private void DataRowView_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // This will be called every time a change is made to any cell
}
```